# matlab mldivide not giving the same answer as direct pseudo inverse

Tags: matlab, least-squares

The problem is very simple. Fitting a quartic curve to some noisy data. Mldivide gives the wrong set of values for the coefficients, while direct computation of pseudo inverse works.

Quartic equation: c0  + c1*t + c2*t^2 + c3*t^3 + c4*t^4

Input file contains t and actual value for each sample.

```
fid = fopen('Data_Corr.txt');

A = zeros(4001,5);

for i = 1:4001
    dataPt = fscanf(fid,'%f',2);
    A(i,:) = [1 dataPt(1) dataPt(1)^2 dataPt(1)^3 dataPt(1)^4];
    b(i) = dataPt(2);
end

%c = b\A; %using matlab mldivide
c = inv(A'*A)*A'*b; %computing pseudo inverse directly

for i = 1:4001
    d(i) = A(i,1)*c(1) + A(i,2)*c(2) + A(i,3)*c(3) + A(i,4)*c(4) + A(i,5)*c(5);
end

figure; hold on; grid on;
plot(b,'-b');
plot(d,'r-');
```

Comment: Never use inv, use pinv instead. Try pinv(A)*b or pinv(A'*A)*A'*b , the second should give the same result to \

Comment: mldivide chooses different algorithms depending on the type of matrices (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553210/how-to-implement-matlabs-mldivide-a-k-a-the-backslash-operator). It is hard to say what was chosen because you did not provide Data_Corr.txt. Why do you think that it is "wrong"? Maybe your criteria of "right" fitting is not equclidean norm?

Comment: The data is here: https://sites.google.com/site/haripkannan/Home/data/Data_Corr.txt However, the problem was wrong usage of the backslash, it should have been A\b.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I interpret your formula and your code right, `A` stands in for the powers of t and `b` contains the data you are trying to model. Using `c` for the coefficient vector, the equation you want to solve would therefore be

```
b = A * c
```

Solving this using `mldivide` leads to

```
c = A \ b
```

while solving it using `pinv` results in

```
c = pinv(A) * b
```

Your code contains a line corresponding to the second of these two equations, in the form `c = inv(A'*A)*A'*b`. Your use of the backslash operator, however, is the wrong way around.

I strongly suspect that your mismatch comes from this error.

---

If after correcting it the mismatch still exists, the second possibility is that your linear system is not sufficiently determined by the data. In that case, using `pinv` you get the solution with the minimum sum of squares of the coefficients, `sum(c .^ 2)`, while `mldivide` produces a solution with zero coefficients, a "sparse" solution. How exactly this solution is arrived at depends, as @Dmitry pointed out, on the precise properties of the matrices involved. An example:

```
A = [1 2 0; 0 4 3];
b = [8; 18];
c_mldivide = A \ b
c_pinv = pinv(A) * b
```

gives the output

```
c_mldivide =

                     0
                     4
      0.66666666666667


c_pinv =

     0.918032786885245
      3.54098360655738
      1.27868852459016
```

Because the 3 coefficients of the system are constrained by only 2 data points, one of them can be effectively freely chosen.

In your case I doubt that this is the case because a linear system with 5 coefficients should be well determined by 4001 data points, unless the data are highly redundant.