# Multi-variable Fitness Function error using Optimization Tool

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm, genetic-programming

I have the following fitness function:

```
function f = objfun(x,t)
f =  x.*(t-x);
end
```

When i try to use this code as a fitness function using MATLAB's Optimization Tool and the Genetic Algorithm (ga) solver, i get the following error:

`Error running optimization. Not enough input arguments.`

I know the function has only 2 variables and I'm passing it those few variables so I have no idea why I am getting this error.

Can someone please help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I never worked in Matlab because I heard that is slow (see for instance this thread: [Performance Tradeoff - When is MATLAB better/slower than C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20513071/performance-tradeoff-when-is-matlab-better-slower-than-c-c)).

for genetic algorithms you need the highest speed possible because for complex problems you need very large populations...

I suggest to use C/C++. Here is a very light C implementation of a Genetic Algorithm that I've made for solving the function optimization problem: http://create-technology.blogspot.ro/2015/03/a-genetic-algorithm-for-solving.html