# My example shows SVD is less numerically stable than QR decomposition

Tags: matlab, least-squares, svd, matrix-decomposition, qr-decomposition

I asked this question in Math Stackexchange, but it seems it didn't get enough attention there so I am asking it here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1729946/why-do-we-say-svd-can-handle-singular-matrx-when-doing-least-square-comparison?noredirect=1#comment3530971_1729946

I learned from some tutorials that SVD should be more stable than QR decomposition when solving Least Square problem, and it is able to handle singular matrix. But the following example I wrote in matlab seems to support the opposite conclusion. I don't have a deep understanding of SVD, so if you could look at my questions in the old post in Math StackExchange and explain it to me, I would appreciate a lot.

I use a matrix that have a large condition number(e+13). The result shows SVD get a much larger error(0.8) than QR(e-27)

```
% we do a linear regression between Y and X
data= [
47.667483331 -122.1070832;
47.667483331001 -122.1070832
];
X = data(:,1);
Y = data(:,2);

X_1 =  [ones(length(X),1),X];

%%
%SVD method
[U,D,V] = svd(X_1,'econ');
beta_svd = V*diag(1./diag(D))*U'*Y;


%% QR method(here one can also use "\" operator, which will get the same result as I tested. I just wrote down backward substitution to educate myself)
[Q,R] = qr(X_1)
%now do backward substitution
[nr nc] = size(R)
beta_qr=[]
Y_1 = Q'*Y
for i = nc:-1:1
    s = Y_1(i)
    for j = m:-1:i+1
        s = s - R(i,j)*beta_qr(j)
    end
    beta_qr(i) = s/R(i,i)
end

svd_error = 0;
qr_error = 0;
for i=1:length(X)
   svd_error = svd_error + (Y(i) - beta_svd(1) - beta_svd(2) * X(i))^2;
   qr_error = qr_error + (Y(i) - beta_qr(1) - beta_qr(2) * X(i))^2;
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You SVD-based approach is basically the same as the [`pinv` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pinv.html) in MATLAB (see [Pseudo-inverse and SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Singular_value_decomposition_.28SVD.29)). What you are missing though (for numerical reasons) is using a tolerance value such that any singular values less than this tolerance are treated as zero.

If you refer to `edit pinv.m`, you can see something like the following (I won't post the exact code here because the file is copyrighted to MathWorks):

```
[U,S,V] = svd(A,'econ');
s = diag(S);
tol = max(size(A)) * eps(norm(s,inf));
% .. use above tolerance to truncate singular values
invS = diag(1./s);
out = V*invS*U';
```

In fact `pinv` has a second syntax where you can explicitly specify the tolerance value `pinv(A,tol)` if the default one is not suitable...

---

So when solving a least-squares problem of the form `minimize norm(A*x-b)`, you should understand that the `pinv` and `mldivide` solutions have different properties:

- `x = pinv(A)*b` is characterized by the fact that `norm(x)` is smaller than the norm of any other solution.
- `x = A\b` has the fewest possible nonzero components (i.e sparse).

---

Using your example *(note that `rcond(A)` is very small near machine epsilon)*:

```
data = [
    47.667483331    -122.1070832;
    47.667483331001 -122.1070832
];
A = [ones(size(data,1),1), data(:,1)];
b = data(:,2);
```

Let's compare the two solutions:

```
x1 = A\b;
x2 = pinv(A)*b;
```

First you can see how `mldivide` returns a solution `x1` with one zero component (this is obviously a valid solution because you can solve both equations by multiplying by zero as in `b + a*0 = b`):

```
>> sol = [x1 x2]
sol =
 -122.1071   -0.0537
         0   -2.5605
```

Next you see how `pinv` returns a solution `x2` with a smaller norm:

```
>> nrm = [norm(x1) norm(x2)]
nrm =
  122.1071    2.5611
```

Here is the error of both solutions which is acceptably very small:

```
>> err = [norm(A*x1-b) norm(A*x2-b)]
err =
   1.0e-11 *
         0    0.1819
```

Note that use `mldivide`, `linsolve`, or `qr` will give pretty much same results:

```
>> x3 = linsolve(A,b)
Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be inaccurate. RCOND =  2.159326e-16. 
x3 =
 -122.1071
         0

>> [Q,R] = qr(A); x4 = R\(Q'*b)
x4 =
 -122.1071
         0
```

Comment: btw if you follow the chart in the algorithm section of [`mldivide`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18553768/97160), you can see that it's not necessarily performing QR decomposition in your case: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html#moreabout

Answer (score 2):

SVD can handle rank-deficiency. The diagonal matrix D has a near-zero element in your code and you need use pseudoinverse for SVD, i.e. set the 2nd element of 1./diag(D) to 0 other than the huge value (10^14). You should find SVD and QR have equally good accuracy in your example. For more information, see this document http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall11/cos323/notes/cos323_f11_lecture09_svd.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Try this SVD version called block SVD - you just set the iterations equal to the accuracy you want - usually 1 is enough.  If you want all the factors (this has a default # selected for factor reduction) then edit the line k= to the size(matrix) if I recall my MATLAB correctly

```
A= randn(100,5000);
A=corr(A);
% A is your correlation matrix
tic
k = 1000; % number of factors to extract
bsize = k +50;
block = randn(size(A,2),bsize);
iter = 2; % could set via tolerance

[block,R] = qr(A*block,0);
for i=1:iter
    [block,R] = qr(A*(A'*block),0);
end
M = block'*A;
% Economy size dense SVD.
[U,S] = svd(M,0);
U = block*U(:,1:k);
S = S(1:k,1:k);
% Note SVD of a symmetric matrix is:
% A = U*S*U' since V=U in this case, S=eigenvalues, U=eigenvectors
V=real(U*sqrt(S)); %scaling matrix for simulation
toc
% reduced randomized matrix for simulation
sims = 2000;
randnums = randn(k,sims);
corrrandnums = V*randnums;
est_corr_matrix = corr(corrrandnums');
total_corrmatrix_difference =sum(sum(est_corr_matrix-A))
```