# how to solve 6 unknowns from 6 linear equations in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, opencv, equation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [System of linear equations in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474432/system-of-linear-equations-in-c)

Hi Is there any built in function to solve the linear equations with 6 unknowns.
Assume we have 6 equation as well.

Is there any easy and efficient way to solve these equations?

Comment: C and C++ do not have built in matrix libraries.  You should consider looking into a third-party library for this, or switching to a language like MATLAB with built-in support.

Comment: No.  There is no *built-in* (standard) C or C++ library that does linear algebra.

Comment: Yeah, you could write the matrix functions yourself, or just use a library.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this with OpenCV

Comment: use cv::solve(). You might to restructure your matrices to solve homogeneous (Mx=0) or non homogeneous (Mx=a) systems.