# Templated linear equation system solver, C++

Tags: c++, linear-equation

I'm searching for a C++ library to solve linear equation systems. The problem is we need to use a special (rational) data type. Is there any templated library for this purpose?

Comment: possible duplicate of [System of linear equations in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474432/system-of-linear-equations-in-c)

Comment: Belongs on http://google.stackexchange.net

Comment: @djf: it's not a duplicate because a _templated_ library is required. The answers below are already helpful, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look into Eigen:
"Eigen is a C++ template library for linear algebra: matrices, vectors, numerical solvers, and related algorithms"

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

Answer (score 2):

I believe this library may be what you're looking for. It is templated http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm